# Boost libraries are not found, although intellisense sees them

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get the Boost library working.

I have included the path in my c_cpp_properties.json

```
"includePath": [
                "C:\\MinGW\\boost_1_70_0"
            ]
```

although IntelliSense finds the libraries after I try to #include them, when actually #including them i get this error:

```
fatal error: boost/lexical_cast.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

I am missing something?

Comment: What build system do you use for your project? (i.e. CMake, SCons, etc.)

Comment: I installed the MinGW g++ compiler and use that

Comment: IntelliSense != build system. You have to tell your compiler or build system where the boost files are.

Comment: You can tell gcc which directories to use to search for includes and libraries and which libraries to link with, but it's even better to use an existing build system like CMake. It won't take much time to learn basics of them but it will be very useful later and allow you not to go into details of each concrete compiler you use to compile your program.

Comment: Also, AFAIK boost supplies libraries build with MSVC, they are probably won't be linked against program built with gcc.

Comment: @RealFresh If MSVC delivers a `lib` or a `dll`, why should `MinGW` not be able to link them? It still operates on windows ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: MSVC and MinGW (gcc) have different name mangling. There's a bunch of answers on the subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977971/using-msvc-lib-files-with-mingw-name-mangling or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529770/how-to-use-libraries-compiled-with-mingw-in-msvc

Comment: @RealFresh why is `MinGW` itself having a wiki entry that says otherwise? mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls （´-`）.｡oO( ... )