# MINGW vs VS Compiler on QT

Tags: qt

If I compile **OpenCV** using **MinGW MakeFiles** in **CMAKE**.Would I be able to use it on QT that uses Visual Studio Compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends - which compiler are you using. If you compile OpenCV using CL (the GnuMakefile calls CL and not GCC) it will work. Compiling using gcc and using this in MSVC/CL will fail.

Each compiler uses another ABI. Don't match them - it will not work (linker will complain for example if you replace DLLs on runtime).

See also: [Using MSVC++ .lib files with mingw. Name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977971/using-msvc-lib-files-with-mingw-name-mangling)
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands